# can't install webpay extension with php?

Tags: php, swig, php-extension

I am trying to install webpaySWIG extension in my local but it shows some errors.

what i have done is

1. `cd webpaySWIG-3.2` (this is the location for extesion)
2. `sudo make -f makefilePhp5` (this command is mentioned in their document)

while compiling I got the following error

> fatal error: zend.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I had a similar problem recently.

You will need to update the `makefilePhp5` to include the correct php include directory.

Usually it is:

```
PHP_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/php/
```

However if you are running on Zend Server it's:

```
PHP_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/local/zend/include/php/
```

If it's not in either of those do a search for `zend.h` and use that directory instead.

Comment: i had this problem, i tried using the include path shown by phpinfo as suggested in the api guide, but doing the search for zend.h and using that, which was /usr/include/php5 worked

Answer (score 1):

Also i had problems with the linked library names the extension was looking for to be loaded with. Here you can find out the missing files:

```
root@vps:~/webpaySWIG-3.3# ldd /usr/lib/php5/20100525/libwebpayclient.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff745fe000)
        libssl.so.6 => not found
        libcrypto.so.6 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f396b28a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f396b008000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f396adf2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f396aa66000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f396b7c6000)
```

then find what ever your current versions name is for each missing and create a symlink to it, in my case:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.6    
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well, but was able to get it successfully installed after a lot of hassle.

To save other developers time, I've put together [a library to wrap around the Webpay extension](https://github.com/mitchdav/st-george-ipg). It includes a Docker container with the extension installed, and has a testsuite to check connectivity against St.George's test servers.

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly one reference on the internet for "webpaySWIG" other than this question, and that's in [this PDF document that seems to be an **installation guide**](https://www.ipg.stgeorge.com.au/downloads/Linux_API_Developer_Guide_v3.2.pdf).  You would do well to read it, especially the bits about required packages.  It looks like you're missing the PHP development packages.

It should be noted that the guide mentions using `dl()`, a function recently *removed* from PHP.  You will need to load the extension in php.ini instead.

Comment: That's because it's a St George Internet Payment Gateway module. https://www.ipg.stgeorge.com.au/download.asp

Comment: dl: Warning
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: so yeah you add extension=webpay_php.so to your php.ini